# Room Persistance Library: Cannot find implementation for ContactAppDatabase (ContactAppDatabase_Impl does not exist)

Tags: android, android-room, android-jetpack-compose

I am implementing Room database for storing contacts for the **jetpack compose** project on **Android Studio Bumblebee 2021.1.1 Canary 10**. But I am getting an error as shown below

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.tana.contactapp, PID: 8843
java.lang.RuntimeException: cannot find implementation for com.tana.contactapp.data.ContactAppDatabase. ContactAppDatabase_Impl does not exist
```

Here is my app-level **Gradle file**

```
    plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
}

android {
    compileSdk 30

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.tana.contactapp"
        minSdk 22
        targetSdk 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion compose_version
    }
    packagingOptions {
        resources {
            excludes += '/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0'
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.material:material:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.material:material-icons-core:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.material:material-icons-extended:$compose_version"
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.room:room-ktx:2.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-livedata:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.4.0-alpha06'
    annotationProcessor 'androidx.room:room-compiler:2.3.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:$compose_version"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_version"
}
```

Here is the **project-level Gradle** file

```
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

buildscript {
    ext {
        compose_version = '1.0.2'
    }
}
```

Here is **settings.gradle** file

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    plugins {
        id 'com.android.application' version '7.1.0-alpha10'
        id 'com.android.library' version '7.1.0-alpha10'
        id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.5.21'
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
rootProject.name = "ContactApp"
include ':app'
```

Here is my **Entity** File

```
package com.tana.contactapp.data

import androidx.compose.material.icons.Icons
import androidx.compose.material.icons.filled.Person
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.vector.ImageVector
import androidx.room.Entity
import androidx.room.Ignore
import androidx.room.PrimaryKey

@Entity(tableName = "contacts")
data class Contact(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) val id: Long = 0,
    val name: String,
    val number: String,
    @Ignore val imageDp: ImageVector = Icons.Default.Person
)
```

Here is my **DAO** File

```
package com.tana.contactapp.data

import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData
import androidx.room.*

@Dao
interface ContactAppDao {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM contacts")
    fun getContacts(): LiveData<List<Contact>>

    @Insert
    suspend fun addContact(contact: Contact)

    @Update
    suspend fun updateContact(contact: Contact)

    @Delete
    suspend fun deleteContact(contact: Contact)

    @Query("DELETE FROM contacts")
    suspend fun deleteContacts()
}
```

Here is my **Database** File

```
package com.tana.contactapp.data
import android.content.Context
import androidx.room.Database
import androidx.room.Room
import androidx.room.RoomDatabase

@Database(entities = [Contact::class], version = 1, exportSchema = false)
abstract class ContactAppDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun contactsDao(): ContactAppDao

    companion object {
        private var INSTANCE: ContactAppDatabase? = null

        fun getDatabase(context: Context): ContactAppDatabase {
            synchronized(this) {
                var instance = INSTANCE
                if (instance == null) {
                    instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                        context.applicationContext,
                        ContactAppDatabase::class.java,
                        "contact_app_database"
                    ).build()
                }
                return instance
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried a lot of solutions from the previous questions similar to this but none seems to work for my case

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove

```
annotationProcessor 'androidx.room:room-compiler:2.3.0'
```

and add room compiler using `kapt`

```
kapt androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version
```

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/room#kts

and kapt plugin, on top of your root gradle file

```
apply plugin: "kotlin-kapt"
```

Comment: Adding kotlin-kapt returns this error.UnknownPluginException: Plugin [id: 'kotlin-kapt'] was not found in any of the following sources:

Comment: you get this error when you add id 'kotlin-kapt' ?

Comment: How your both gradle looks like top-level and app level?

Comment: This is how the project was created in the android studio bumblebee canary 10 and above. I didn't add a single gradle file

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by adding id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt' version '1.5.21' in settings.gradle file plugins section, and then adding id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt' in app gradle file instead of 'kotlin-kapt'

Comment: both are same. and you should still be using `kapt` instead of `annotationprocessor`

Comment: Yes I changed it to kapt instead of annotationprocessor